# Concatenate a List of Char into a String via a fold

Tags: scala

For a list of string, I do this:

```
val l = List("a", "r", "e")                    
l.reduceLeft((x, z) => x + z)
```

I don't know how to do it for a list of Chars. The following is a compile error:

```
val chs = List('a', 'r', 'e')
chs.reduceLeft[String]( (x,y) => String.valueOf(x) + String.valueOf(y))
```

Comment: You could just use `mkString`!

Comment: I want to learn how to use folds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to really learn `fold`s, you should do something a bit more applicable. While you can of course do this to a string, there are much better ways to create a string from a list of characters. Folds are very powerful and creating a string doesn't quite do it justice

Let's say, for example, you have

```
case class Employee(fname:String, lname:String, age:Int)
```

Let's say you also have a `HashMap[String, List[Employee]]` that organizes them by position. So you have Joe Shmoe who's a 25 year old Software Engineer, and Larry Larison who's a 37 year old accountant, etc. You can easily use a fold to organize this data into flat structures very simply. If you want to take it and create just a List of the names of your employees you can combine it with a `flatMap` to very simply return a `List[String]`

```
val employees = Map[String, List[Employee]]("Software Engineer" -> List(new Employee("Joe", "Shmoe", 25), new Employee("Larry", "Larrison", 37)), "Accountant" -> List(new Employee("Harry", "Harrison", 55))).flatMap(_._2).foldLeft[List[String]](Nil)((l,e) => e.fname + " " + e.lname :: l)

employees.flatMap(_._2).foldLeft[List[String]](Nil)(
  (li,emp) => 
    s"${emp.fname} ${emp.lname}" :: li
)
```

The `flatMap` function gives you a flat list of all `Employee` objects. It's passed a `Tuple2` of `String` and `List[Employee]`. The `_._2` returns the 2nd item of the `Tuple2` which is the list of employees which `flatMap` joins together with the others.

From there, you can use `foldLeft` on a list of `Employee` objects to create a list of their names. `Nil` is an empty `List` (and will have `List[String]` inferred), that's your starting object.

`foldLeft` takes a predicate that should use a tuple as it's parameter, the first item of which will be the list formed so far, and the second item of which will be the next item in the list you are iterating over. on the first pass, you'll have an empty list and Joe Shmoe.

In the predicate, you create the string of the `Employee`s first and last name and prepend that string to the accumulator, `li`.

This returns

```
List[String] = List(Harry Harrison, Larry Larrison, Joe Shmoe)
```

Folds are a very useful tool. I've found this page to be very helpful in figuring them out: http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/30/lots-and-lots-of-foldleft-examples/

Answer (score 6):

Here's the type signature for `reduceLeft`:

```
def reduceLeft[B >: A](f: (B, A) => B): B
```

It requires that what you're reducing to be a subtype of the type that you're reducing from so in you're case `Char` is `A` and `String` is `B` which is not a subtype of `Char`.

You can do a foldLeft which will reduce your list and doesn't require the output to be a subtype of the input:

```
chs.foldLeft("")((x,y) => x + String.valueOf(y))
```

Comment: congrats for answering the actual question asked

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to accomplish the result:

```
scala> List('a', 'r', 'e').mkString
res0: String = are
```

Answer (score 0):

To to show the workings of `foldLeft` and `foldRight` (and `map`, along the way) with a little bit af a "real" operation applied, let's use `toChar` (of `Int`):

```
val iA: Int = 65
val cA: Char = iA.toChar //====> A
val cB: Char = 66.toChar //====> B
cA + cB
//====> 131            (Int), since char has no concatenation +, obviously
"" + cA + cB
//====> AB             now forced to concatenation + of String

val li: List[Int] = List(65, 66, 67)
li map (i => i.toChar)   //====> List(A, B, C)
```

The parameter of `foldLeft` and `foldRight` is the "zero element".

I make it explicitly visible here by using `"0"`, you want to use `""` for a decent concatenation.

The zero element should generally not be part of the result, but is needed to calculate that result.

In The following code:

`i: Int` because of `li: List[Int]`

`acc: String` because of `"0"` (accumulator)

`+` is String concatenation

```
li.foldLeft("0")((acc, i) => acc + i.toChar)
//====> 0ABC     0 --> 0A --> 0AB --> 0ABC
li.foldLeft("0")((acc, i) => i.toChar + acc)
//====> CBA0     0 --> A0 --> BA0 --> CBA0

li.foldRight("0")((i, acc) => acc + i.toChar)
//====> 0CBA     0 --> 0C --> 0CB --> 0CBA
li.foldRight("0")((i, acc) => i.toChar + acc)
//====> ABC0     0 --> C0 --> BC0 --> ABC0
```